# Cache migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, intersystems-cache, intersystems, intersystems-ensemble

The below URL gives insight into how to migrate from sql to cache.

http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GTSQ

Is it possible to do the same in reverse - Cache database to SQL database? I would like to use Ensemble with SQL database. What could be the overhead if i need to migrate the Cache database with an SQL database.

Comment: What kind or flavor of SQL? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s I have added the tags now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ensemble would use embedded database (same engine as Cache') to store operational data such as message traces, logs, business rules etc. If you are thinking of replacing this database - you are out of luck. It is deeply integrated and not designed to be database-agnostic.

However - if you want to use Ensemble to integrate with your database, for instance - process HL7 messages in Ensemble and eventually store some processing result in your SQL database - that's totally supported scenario. Take a read on Ensemble's SQL Adapter http://docs.intersystems.com/documentation/ensemble/20161/pdfs/ESQL.pdf

Answer (score 1):

InterSystems Caché supports ODBC connection, so, you can migrate any SQL which you need. Any other types of data not so easy to migrate. To migrate it you should exactly know how stores data, and export for example in some text files with delimiters, and then import it in any other systems.